# Negamax implementation doesn't appear to work with tic-tac-toe

Tags: c++, algorithm, ai

I've implemented Negamax as it can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax), which includes alpha/beta pruning.

However, it seems to favor a losing move, which should be an invalid result.

The game is Tic-Tac-Toe, I've abstracted most of the game play so it should be rather easy to spot an error within the algorithm.

Here is the code, `nextMove`, `negamax` or `evaluate` are probably the functions that contain the fault:

```
#include <list>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

//#define DEBUG 1

using namespace std;

struct Move {
    int row, col;

    Move(int row, int col) : row(row), col(col) { }
    Move(const Move& m) { row = m.row; col = m.col; }
};

struct Board {
    char player;
    char opponent;
    char board[3][3];

    Board() { }

    void read(istream& stream) {
        stream >> player;
        opponent = player == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                char playa;

                stream >> playa;
                board[row][col] = playa == '_' ? 0 : playa == player ? 1 : -1;
            }
        }
    }

    void print(ostream& stream) {
        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                switch(board[row][col]) {
                    case -1:
                        stream << opponent;
                        break;

                    case 0:
                        stream << '_';
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        stream << player;
                        break;

                }
            }
            stream << endl;
        }
    }

    void do_move(const Move& move, int player) {
        board[move.row][move.col] = player;
    }

    void undo_move(const Move& move) {
        board[move.row][move.col] = 0;
    }

    bool isWon() {
        if (board[0][0] != 0) {
            if (board[0][0] == board[0][1] &&
                    board[0][1] == board[0][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][0] == board[1][0] &&
                    board[1][0] == board[2][0])
                return true;
        }

        if (board[2][2] != 0) {
            if (board[2][0] == board[2][1] &&
                    board[2][1] == board[2][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][2] == board[1][2] &&
                    board[1][2] == board[2][2])
                return true;
        }

        if (board[1][1] != 0) {
            if (board[0][1] == board[1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[2][1])
                return true;

            if (board[1][0] == board[1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[1][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[2][2])
                return true;

            if (board[0][2] == board [1][1] &&
                    board[1][1] == board[2][0])
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    list<Move> getMoves() {
        list<Move> moveList;

        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
            for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
                if (board[row][col] == 0)
                    moveList.push_back(Move(row, col));

        return moveList;
    }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& stream, Board& board) {
    board.print(stream);
    return stream;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& stream, Board& board) {
    board.read(stream);
    return stream;
}

int evaluate(Board& board) {
    int score = board.isWon() ? 100 : 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
            if (board.board[row][col] == 0)
                score += 1;

    return score;
}

int negamax(Board& board, int depth, int player, int alpha, int beta) {
    if (board.isWon() || depth <= 0) {
#if DEBUG > 1
        cout << "Found winner board at depth " << depth << endl;
        cout << board << endl;
#endif
        return player * evaluate(board);
    }

    list<Move> allMoves = board.getMoves();

    if (allMoves.size() == 0)
        return player * evaluate(board);

    for(list<Move>::iterator it = allMoves.begin(); it != allMoves.end(); it++) {
        board.do_move(*it, -player);
        int val = -negamax(board, depth - 1, -player, -beta, -alpha);
        board.undo_move(*it);

        if (val >= beta)
            return val;

        if (val > alpha)
            alpha = val;
    }

    return alpha;
}

void nextMove(Board& board) {
    list<Move> allMoves = board.getMoves();
    Move* bestMove = NULL;
    int bestScore = INT_MIN;

    for(list<Move>::iterator it = allMoves.begin(); it != allMoves.end(); it++) {
        board.do_move(*it, 1);
        int score = -negamax(board, 100, 1, INT_MIN + 1, INT_MAX);
        board.undo_move(*it);

#if DEBUG
        cout << it->row << ' ' << it->col << " = " << score << endl;
#endif

        if (score > bestScore) {
            bestMove = &*it;
            bestScore = score;
        }
    }

    if (!bestMove)
        return;

    cout << bestMove->row << ' ' << bestMove->col << endl;

#if DEBUG
    board.do_move(*bestMove, 1);
    cout << board;
#endif

}

int main() {
    Board board;

    cin >> board;
#if DEBUG
    cout << "Starting board:" << endl;
    cout << board;
#endif

    nextMove(board);
    return 0;
}
```

Giving this input:

```
O
X__
___
___
```

The algorithm chooses to place a piece at 0, 1, causing a guaranteed loss, do to this trap(nothing can be done to win or end in a draw):

```
XO_
X__
___
```

Perhaps it has something to do with the evaluation function? If so, how could I fix it?

Comment: Code comments would really help those who would like to help you without first learning the negamax algorithm and running your code locally.

Comment: What happens after your code reads the last '_' in a row? I would expect a carriage return/line feed test in there. Just by looking, I would expect it to mess up your board array. Not necessarily related to your question, but still possibly a problem.

Comment: Assuming I understand your approach, what do you get if you print out all the negamax scores for each available move? Does (0,1) show the best score? Which move *should* the algorithm make first? What score does it get? Sharing your debug output would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved!

The `evaluate` function did not evaluate the board from the player's perspective, but from a global perspective. Once I fixed this, the negamax algorithm worked like a charm!

Comment: Given that you seem to have solved your problem, you should accept your answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Comment: It would also be extremely helpful if you showed your fixed code, so people can see the difference between what failed and what worked.